# run vue3 ssr on cloudflare workers

Tags: vue.js, cloudflare-workers, vue-ssr

I'm trying to run a vue ssr app on cloudflare workers.

I generated a new project using `wrangler generate test`

I installed vue using `npm install vue@next` and `npm install @vue/server-renderer`

I edited the **index.js** file like this:

```js
const { createSSRApp } = require('vue')
const { renderToString } = require('@vue/server-renderer')

const app = createSSRApp({
  data: () => ({ msg: 'hello' }),
  template: `<div>{{ msg }}</div>`
})

addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
})

async function handleRequest(request) {
  const html = await renderToString(app)
  return new Response(html, {status: 200})
}
```

I then used `wrangler dev` to test it, but when I access the page I get this error:

```
ReferenceError: __VUE_PROD_DEVTOOLS__ is not defined
    at Module.<anonymous> (worker.js:8:104768)
    at n (worker.js:1:110)
    at Object.<anonymous> (worker.js:8:104943)
    at n (worker.js:1:110)
    at worker.js:1:902
    at worker.js:1:912
```

Any help or guidance is appreciated

Comment: Is it *Vue 3* or *Vue 2*?

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue and was able to fix it by defining a global constant (**VUE_PROD_DEVTOOLS** = false) during compile time.

Here is how my webpack prod config looks like:

```js
const webpack = require('webpack');
const { merge } = require("webpack-merge");
const webpackCommon = require("./webpack.common");

const prodConfig = {
    mode: 'production',
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            __VUE_PROD_DEVTOOLS__: JSON.stringify(false)
          }),
    ]
};

module.exports = merge(webpackCommon, prodConfig);
```